# Значение массива из строки по спец. символам PHP

Tags: php, массивы, строки

У меня есть строка:

```
$string = 'Значение //value\\ текст';
```

И массив

```
$array = ['value' => '1488', 'name' => 'Ilya', 'rain' => 'test'];
```

Мне нужно, чтобы когда я вызывал функцию `convertString($string, $array);` у меня выводилось: `Значение 1488 текст`.

Пытался делать через `explode`, не получилось.

Comment: Почему convertString() имеет только один параметр для строки? Как массив передавать?

Comment: @MAX, Думаю нужно через второй параметр, либо `global`

Comment: Заменяйте `//value\\ через str_replace` например и все дела.

Comment: В общем-то @And уже дал ответ. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример функции:

```
function convertString($string, $array)
{
    return preg_replace_callback("~//(.+)\\\\~", function($m) use ($array) {
        return (isset($array[$m[1]])) ? $array[$m[1]] : $m[0];
    }, $string);
}
```

Проверяем функцию:

```
$string = 'Значение //value\\ текст';
$array = ['value' => '1488', 'name' => 'Ilya', 'rain' => 'test'];

echo convertString($string, $array);
```

На выходе получаем:

```
Значение 1488 текст
```

Comment: а зачем `_callback` то здесь?

Comment: Ох, раритетный вопрос всплыл :D

Comment: @teran, ох, приветствую, а я уже и не помню :D

Comment: @teran, вроде бы для проверки в массиве делал кэллбек,.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function convertString($string, $array) {
  $string = explode('//value\\', $string);
  $string = $string[0] . ' ' . $array['value'] . ' ' . $string[1];
  return $string;
}

$string = 'Значение //value\\ текст';
$array = ['value' => '1488', 'name' => 'Ilya', 'rain' => 'test'];

echo convertString($string, $array);
```

Рабочий вариант кода